# Multiple instance of Murmur ( Mumble server )

Tags: debian, hosting, mumble

this is my first time posting here and after a couple hours of searching on different web sites / wiki I'm still trying to find a way to simply host and manage **multiple mumble server** on the same **operating system**.

My goal is to host maybe like 3-4 Mumble servers on my Raspberry Pi 2. I already have my mumble server running and working , but How could I run multiple instances. I know I will have to use different ports and so on , and I think mumble supports virtual servers.

Thanks for your time ! Have a great day

Comment: Are you running this in a business environment?

Comment: Not really , this is more for a educational purpose , I'm still a student as a network administrator , this is my second year in college and I'm trying to understand things and figure things out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run a second and etc instances, few items must to be changed:

1. Change your sqlite file destination (one server per sqlite file)
2. Change your port (one instance per port)
3. Change your Server Name
4. Change log file (You want separate logs don't you?)
5. Change your pid file name
6. murmurd -ini [$ini_file]&

Comment: I could simply make a python script that would change all the things you have stated above , I will test this tonight ! Thanks for sharing this tip !

Comment: Simple and brilliant @Maxiko !!!! Do you know anyway to start that process ( daemon ) after every restart ? The dpkg-reconfigure mumbe-server already offers that option but only for the main server.

Comment: I think you should run your own startup script

Comment: I though so , well Thanks once again ! :)